# Trigger a function after 5 API calls return (in a distributed context)

Tags: software-design, system-design

My girlfriend was asked the below question in an interview:

> We trigger 5 independent APIs simultaneously.  Once they have *all* completed, we want to trigger a function.  How will you design a system to do this?

My girlfriend replied she will use a flag variable, but the interviewer was evidently not happy with it.

So, is there a good way in which this could be handled (in a distributed context)?  Note that each of the 5 API calls are made by different servers and the function to be triggered is on a 6th server.

Comment: Use a flag variable in what way? Did she elaborate or did she say, "I would use a flag variable," and end there? A good answer would take a minute or two to explain.

Comment: She said she would use a flag variable to keep track of the number of API calls that have returned.  The interviewer seemed to suggest using Paxos in some way which she couldn't understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I were asked this, my first thought would be to use [promises/futures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). The idea behind them is that you can execute time-consuming operations asynchronously and they will somehow notify you when they've completed, either successfully or unsuccessfully, typically by calling a callback function. So the first step is to spawn five asynchronous tasks and get five promises.

Then I would [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model) the five promises together, creating a unified promise that represents the five separate tasks. In JavaScript I might call [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all); in Java I would use [`CompletableFuture.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)).

I would want to make sure to handle both success and failure. The combined promise should succeed if all of the API calls succeed and fail if any of them fail. If any fail there should be appropriate error handling/reporting. What happens if multiple calls fail? How would a mix of successes and failures be reported? These would be design points to mention, though not necessarily solve during the interview.

Promises and futures typically have modular layering system that would allow edge cases like timeouts to be handled by chaining handlers together. If done right, timeouts could become just another error condition that would be naturally handled by the error handling already in place.

This solution would not require any state to be shared across threads, so I would not have to worry about mutexes or deadlocks or other thread synchronization problems.

---

> She said she would use a flag variable to keep track of the number of API calls have returned.

One thing that makes great interviewees stand out is their ability to anticipate follow-up questions and explain details before they are asked. The best answers are fully fleshed out. They demonstrate that one has thought through one's answer in detail, and they have minimal handwaving.

When I read the above I have a slew of follow-up questions:

- How will she know when each API call has returned? Is she waiting for a function call to return, a callback to be called, an event to be fired, or a promise to complete?
- How is she causing all of the API calls to be executed concurrently? Is there multithreading, a fork-join pool, multiprocessing, or asynchronous execution?
- Flag variables are booleans. Is she really using a flag, or does she mean a *counter*?
- What is the variable tracking and what code is updating it?
- What is monitoring the variable, what condition is it checking, and what's it doing when the condition is reached?
- If using multithreading, how is she handling synchronization?
- How will she handle edge cases such API calls failing, or timing out?

A flag variable might lead to a workable solution or it might lead nowhere. The only way an interviewer will know which it is is if she thinks about and proactively discusses these various questions. Otherwise, the interviewer will have to pepper her with follow-up questions, and will likely lower their evaluation of her.

When I interview people, my mental grades are something like:

- **S** — Solution works and they addressed all issues without prompting.
- **A** — Solution works, follow-up questions answered satisfactorily.
- **B** — Solution works, explained well, but there's a better solution that more experienced devs would find.
- **C** — What they said is okay, but their depth of knowledge is lacking.
- **F** — Their answer is flat out incorrect, or getting them to explain their answer was like pulling teeth.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers suggesting `Promises` seem to assume all these requests necessarily come from the same client. If the context here is distributed systems, as you said it is, then I don't think those are valid answers. If they were, then the interview question would have nothing to do with distributed systems, except to essay your girlfriend's ability to recognize something that isn't really a distributed systems problem.

And the question does have the shape of some classic problems in distributed systems. It sounds a lot like [YouTube view counting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY_2gElt3SA): How do you achieve qualities like [atomicity and consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) in a multi-threaded, multi-process, or multi-client environment? Failing to recognize this, thinking the answer could be as simple as "a flag", betrayed a lack of experience in distributed systems.

Another thing about that answer is that it leaves many ambiguities. Where does the flag live? As a variable in another (Java?) API? In a database? In a file? Even in a non-distributed context, these are important questions. And if she had gone on to address these questions, even being innocent of all the distributed systems complications, she might have happily fallen into a discussion of the kinds of D.S. problems that occur when you use, say, a file; and how using a ACID-compliant database might solve those problems, and what the tradeoffs might be there... And she might have corrected herself and said "counter" instead of "flag"!